# Use Custom Local Font in WKWebView

Tags: ios, css, swift, fonts, wkwebview

I am attempting to use a local font (one installed with the application) in the CSS of some dynamic HTML presented within a `WKWebView`. I have read numerous Stack Overflow posts and this [webpage](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/). To review what I have done:

The font (in this case `ImpactLTStd.otf`) is part of the iOS application.

It is entered as part of the application plist in the *Fonts provided by application* section.

Per the referenced webpage, I can confirm that the `ImpactLTStd.otf` is listed in the **Copy Bundle Resources** section of **Build Phases** and leads me to believe that the `ImpactLTStd.otf` is being bundled with the application correctly.

The font is listed in the CSS as:

```
<style> @font-face {font-family: 'Impact LT Std'; src: local('Impact LT Std'), local('ImpactLTStd'), url('ImpactLTStd.otf'); format('opentype'); } </style>
```

I reference the font two different ways in this fashion (one by font family and one by font name in order see which one worked and neither did):

```
<style>  .box_root {    overflow: auto;    background-color: #000000;    padding-top: 1.5em;    padding-bottom: 1.5em;    padding-left: 1.5em;    max-width: 1440px;    max-height: 640px;    display: table;  }  .box_title {    color: #ffd300;    line-height: 1em;    font-size: 85pt;    font-size: 6vw;    font-family: 'Impact LT Std';    text-transform: uppercase;  }  .box_description {    padding-top: .5em;    line-height: 1em;    color: #ffffff;    font-size: 65pt;    font-size: 4vw;    font-weight: bold;    font-family: 'ImpactLTStd';  }
```

I load the HTML into the `WKWebView` using `loadHTMLString`:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(getHtml(), baseURL: nil)
```

However, the HTML text that is displayed in the `WKWebView` using the CSS tags does not use the Impact font but instead some default font that looks like Times New Roman.

Anyone have an idea what step I did incorrectly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not provide a base URL when loading the HTML string, this will cause the font failing to load. Try accessing your bundle's main resource path, like this:

```
if let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath {
    let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: resourcePath)
    webView.loadHTMLString(getHtml(), baseURL: url)
}
```

Comment: That was it!  I wonder why none of the other material I looked at ever referenced this important point.  Thanks again ...

Comment: What if we have other content to load which needs base url (like video).How to give the base url and resource path at same time ?

Comment: you saved my day, excelent.